# Firebase GeoFire vs Geofence API

Tags: android, firebase, android-geofence, geofire

Am looking at adding geofencing type capabilities to an app.  Right now I'm already using Firebase and Geofire (https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) and was wondering what, if anything does Google's Geofence API (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence) offer above what can be done directly with Geofire.  It seems that for Geofencing to work I'd need anyway to retrieve set of geofence locations appropriate for my current location (Google allows max 100 of these to be added at any one time).

It does also seem that there might be scenario where these 2 APIs would be used together i.e. use GeoFire to give me set of geofence locations (using say radius of 10km)....and then Geofence API would notify when user is within say 100m of one of those locations.  The question then is how best to "refresh" set of configured geofences as user's location changes.

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/QPju4FBcSBQ, where it might be a better fit.